Help me on this voltage divider question
There is only description of the circuit and a question.

In a voltage divider circuit powered by a 12V source, two resistors R₁ and R₂ are connected in series.
An LED with a forward voltage drop of 2V is connected across R₂.
The voltage across R₂ is found to drop by 70% when a resistor Rx is connected in parallel with the LED.


If the resistance of R₂ is 8 ΚΩ, calculate the resistance value of R₁ and the resistance value of Rx that causes the voltage drop across R2 to decrease by 70%.

From my understanding the circuit will be:

The answers I got are R1 is 40kOhm and Rx is 2.857kOhm. Rx was calculated with assumption R1 is correct and LED was off and open.
Please correct my answer if wrong.


The assumption here is that the LED is not drawing a significant current when it has 2 volts across it.

This means that we know that the 2 volts is purely due to the resistor divider formed by R1 and R2.

Given that R2 is 8 kΩ and the supply is 12 volts, R1 has to be 40 kΩ.


For the voltage across R2 to drop to 30% of 2 volts (a decrease by 70%), the value for R2 in parallel with R3 must create 0.6 volts.

This implies a net resistance of R2||R3 of 2.1053 kΩ.

This means that R3 must be 2.85714275 kΩ.


